# Как использовать прокси с паролем в requests.get

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

У меня прокси формата пользователь:пароль:айпи:порт. Вопрос - как использовать его в requests.get()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45763866/10941639

Comment: делаю как там - не получается

Comment: Код, пример, ошибки, traceback?

Comment: что блин значит не получается?)) верь в себя и все получится. и доку читай https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies